# Multiple queries using IF...ELSE

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

How do I do multiple things within an IF "clause"?  Can I really only perform one action?  I did a search on Google for "sql server scope" but it returned a bunch of unrelated stuff about "scope_identity" and nothing about syntax...

Example:

```
DECLARE @db_level int = 2

DECLARE @db_major int = 1
DECLARE @db_minor int = 0
DECLARE @db_point int = 0

DECLARE @db_current_level int = (SELECT MAX(db_level) FROM db_schema_log_tb)

IF (@db_level > @db_current_level)
    PRINT 'Script failed because database level is higher than script level';
    GOTO ExitScript;
ELSE
    SELECT * FROM custom_tb;

ExitScript:
```

Apparently, ELSE in this script is incorrect syntax, unless I remove the PRINT statement.

Comment: Voting to move to SE as this is a very basic SQL question

Comment: Have you tried lookin up syntax in the manual? Like statement blocks?

Comment: @LowlyDBA Why must “basic” questions be migrated away? Who gets to draw the line that defines “basic”? See here for community consensus: https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/q/755/1186

Comment: [IF...ELSE (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/if-else-transact-sql)

Comment: @AaronBertrand I think a question that can be answered by spending < 5 min reading documentation on a simple feature is "basic," though it isn't always that simple admittedly.. While there seems to be people on both sides in that thread...the [help page](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) still has the migrate-if-basic language so I've been under the impression that stands as appropriate action.

Comment: @LowlyDBA so read the doc hot2use posted. The example doesn’t mention BEGIN / END and if you didn’t know what a statement block was (and that’s not the exact term I would have searched for either), I think you’d have a hard time making the connection too.

Comment: @AaronBertrand True, but there is a link to the aptly named Control-Of-Flow article and BEGIN...END at the end of the (short) document. I'm not sure I agree that the difficulty of finding info in particular documentation weighs heavily on the "basic/not" nature of a question, but I do see your point.

Comment: @LowlyDBA Again, "control-of-flow" may be a term you're familiar with, but it's clearly not something the OP knew to look for. Personally, I don't feel a beginner is any worse off asking a question like this here than they are on Stack Overflow. YMMV. Googling works when you know what to search for, and when you don't know, you ask. This is what we encourage people to do, yet the reaction sadly is often to punish them for it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need a block construct (`BEGIN`/`END`). Personally, I think you should always use them even when you only have one action.

```
IF (somecondition)
BEGIN
  -- do one thing
  -- do another thing
  -- do a third thing
END
ELSE
BEGIN
  -- do the other thing(s)
END
```

Comment: +1 for "I think you should always use them even when you only have one action."